# compute $\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+xy^2)}dxdy$ with the substitution $(x,y)=(u^2,\frac{v}{u})$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to compute $$\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+xy^2)}dxdy$$ using the substitution $(x,y)=(u^2,\frac{v}{u})$.

**Attempt**

The Jacobian is given by  $$\left|\begin{matrix}2u&0\\-\frac{v}{u^2}&\frac{1}{u}\end{matrix}\right|=2.$$
Moreover, $$(x,y)=(u^2,\frac{v}{u})\implies (u,v)=(\sqrt x,y\sqrt x),$$
and thus, if $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$, we have that $(u,v)\in [0,1]^2$.

Therefore, my integral become,
$$2\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2}du\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+v^2}dv=2\arctan(1)^2=2\frac{\pi^2}{16}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$

The problem is that the answer is $\frac{\pi^2}{16}$ as [Wolfram suggest](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20(1%2F((1%2Bx)(1%2Bxy%5E2)))%20dx%20dy,%20x%3D0%20to%201,%20y%3D0%20to%201) and my teacher suggest also, but I don't see where is my mistakes. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $0\leq y=\frac{v}{u}\leq 1$ as $u=\sqrt{x}\in [0,1]$, it should be
$$2\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2}\left(\int_0^{u}\frac{dv}{1+v^2}\right)du=
2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(u)}{1+u^2}du=\left[\arctan^2(u)\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi^2}{16}.$$

Comment: how do you see that $(u,v)\in [0,1]\times [0,u]$ ?

Comment: @MSE Because $0\leq y=v/u\leq 1$ as $u=\sqrt{x}\in [0,1]$.